# Where do I get the JOGL JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jogl

This might sound silly... but I don't know where to find the JOGL JAR.
I searched their website (http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) and couldn't find it.

Could someone please help?

Thank you

blargman

Comment: I'm currently on MAC OS X running an AMD Video Card.

Comment: Not that silly. I couldn't find it off the link you provived either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can get the files from here: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL.

Just follow one of these links: [Signed Release](http://jogamp.org/deployment/webstart/archive/), [Signed Candidate](http://jogamp.org/deployment/webstart-next/archive/), [Candidate](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/archive/), off the above Wiki page to get list of files.

You'll need the macosx for jogl and possibly the gluegen one as well.

Here are steps on how to setup [JOGL in an IDE](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE).

Comment: sorry to pester you... but i'm not exactly sure what you mean by compiled files. The website has no jars where i can simply add to eclipse.

Comment: A required library that does the binding to the C interface: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlueGen, that is probably bundled with the JOGL download.

Comment: As of 2014-01-11, there is not jogl.jar to be found under any of those links.

Comment: @andreasdr jogl.jar has been renamed jogl-all.jar. The JARs are stored in jogamp-all-platforms.7z It's better that way as some web browsers break the JARs when you download them directly (they wrap them into ZIPs for "security purposes").